# IPOPT solution is not optimal

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I am trying to minimize a non-linear objective function with IPOPT, and it's returning a solution that is not optimal.

Even if I use the optimal solution as the starting point, IPOPT converges to a worse solution.

This is the output when I run with a bad starting point:

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  1.5915818e+00 4.39e+04 1.00e+00  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0 
   1r 1.5915818e+00 4.39e+04 9.99e+02   3.4 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 5.24e-14R  2 
   2r 1.5916062e+00 4.39e+04 9.99e+02   3.4 2.47e+05    -  6.88e-07 3.09e-05f  6 
   3r 1.5913804e+00 4.39e+04 9.98e+02   3.4 1.28e+05    -  1.39e-02 5.24e-04f  1 Nhj 
   4r 1.7302195e+00 3.47e+04 1.60e+04   3.4 1.17e+05    -  4.36e-03 1.70e-01f  1 
   5  1.7259751e+00 3.48e+04 2.47e+00  -1.0 1.71e+05    -  8.34e-02 2.23e-03h  1 Nhj 
   6  1.7259180e+00 3.49e+04 8.31e+00  -1.0 1.69e+05    -  5.66e-04 3.05e-05h  1 
   7  1.7213054e+00 3.48e+04 2.40e+00  -1.0 1.60e+05    -  2.83e-05 2.57e-03f  1 
   8  1.7156613e+00 3.47e+04 2.36e+00  -1.0 1.59e+05    -  2.10e-03 3.17e-03h  1 
   9  1.7153077e+00 3.46e+04 2.38e+00  -1.0 1.61e+05    -  7.58e-04 1.97e-04h  1 
...
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  82  5.2283523e-02 1.09e-11 1.32e-07  -8.6 3.57e-02  -5.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1 LA
  83  5.2283284e-02 1.46e-11 1.31e-07  -8.6 1.06e-01  -5.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  84  5.2282973e-02 2.91e-11 6.68e-06  -8.6 3.02e-01  -6.4 1.00e+00 4.53e-01h  1 L
  85  5.2282772e-02 5.96e-08 4.90e-08  -8.6 3.57e-01  -6.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1 LA
  86  5.2281822e-02 2.18e-11 4.81e-08  -8.6 1.05e+00  -7.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  87  5.2279361e-02 2.18e-11 4.47e-08  -8.6 2.93e+00  -7.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  88  5.2273070e-02 2.21e-11 3.66e-08  -8.6 7.20e+00  -8.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  89  5.2260125e-02 2.91e-11 2.19e-08  -8.6 1.29e+01  -8.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  90  5.2241683e-02 2.91e-11 1.31e-08  -9.0 2.31e+01  -9.2 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  91  5.2227314e-02 2.91e-11 7.68e-09  -9.0 4.08e+01  -9.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 L
```

And this is the output when I run with the optimal solution as the starting point:

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  4.2238263e-02 7.20e-10 1.00e+00  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0 
   1  4.2238710e-02 9.13e-10 6.51e+06  -1.0 2.34e+00    -  2.53e-07 6.51e-01f  1 
   2  4.2238710e-02 9.02e-10 3.42e+06  -1.0 8.14e+02    -  7.01e-01 7.01e-07f  1 Nhj 
   3  4.2240948e-02 1.82e-11 2.40e+06  -1.0 8.85e-01    -  1.98e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
   4  4.2243737e-02 1.82e-11 5.15e+05  -1.0 1.10e+00    -  7.85e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
   5  4.2256686e-02 1.46e-11 3.29e+05  -1.0 5.09e+00    -  3.62e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
   6  4.2276907e-02 3.64e-11 7.15e+04  -1.0 7.89e+00    -  7.82e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
   7  4.2358872e-02 7.28e-12 4.53e+04  -1.0 3.46e+01    -  3.67e-01 8.98e-01f  1 
   8  4.2500557e-02 3.64e-11 9.56e+03  -1.0 5.16e+01    -  7.89e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
   9  4.2549360e-02 1.46e-11 2.77e+06  -1.7 9.32e+01    -  7.48e-01 4.02e-01f  1 
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  10  4.3022272e-02 5.82e-11 4.81e+05  -1.7 2.12e+02    -  7.61e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
  11  4.3237732e-02 1.46e-11 3.11e+05  -1.7 1.08e+03    -  3.54e-01 1.11e-01f  1 
  12  4.6695825e-02 4.66e-10 1.35e+05  -1.7 1.33e+03    -  5.65e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
  13  4.8140406e-02 4.66e-10 7.16e+04  -1.7 3.20e+03    -  4.71e-01 1.65e-01f  1 
  14  6.8543786e-02 1.86e-09 2.54e+04  -1.7 4.66e+03    -  6.45e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
  15  7.7732125e-02 7.28e-12 1.45e+04  -1.7 9.09e+03    -  4.29e-01 2.44e-01f  1 
  16  1.3194167e-01 1.46e-11 3.45e+03  -1.7 1.21e+04    -  7.62e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
  17  1.5738427e-01 1.46e-11 2.23e-07  -1.7 2.79e+04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1 
  18  9.7878546e-02 1.49e-08 1.46e+05  -8.6 2.56e+04    -  6.29e-01 7.02e-01f  1 
  19  8.5848103e-02 2.91e-11 6.48e+04  -8.6 1.13e+04    -  7.43e-01 5.71e-01f  1 
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  20  7.6224343e-02 1.49e-08 1.95e+03  -8.6 1.74e+04    -  6.69e-01 7.60e-01f  1 
  21  7.2006155e-02 1.09e-11 2.87e+04  -8.6 7.50e+03    -  7.52e-01 2.76e-01f  1 
  22  6.0908188e-02 7.59e-12 6.76e+03  -8.6 6.88e+03    -  8.01e-01 7.77e-01f  1 
  23  5.6481364e-02 2.98e-08 2.71e+03  -8.6 2.67e+03    -  8.92e-01 6.92e-01f  1 
  24  5.3171781e-02 1.46e-11 1.74e+02  -8.6 3.88e+03    -  8.61e-01 9.28e-01f  1 
  25  5.2347678e-02 1.49e-08 1.40e+00  -8.6 2.14e+03    -  9.70e-01 1.00e+00f  1 
  26  5.2289596e-02 2.98e-08 1.34e-02  -8.6 8.67e+03    -  9.90e-01 5.25e-01h  1 
  27  5.2234159e-02 1.46e-11 3.65e-12  -8.6 5.00e+04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1 A
  28  5.2234158e-02 5.96e-08 2.22e-08  -8.6 2.22e-04  -4.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  29  5.2234158e-02 2.91e-11 1.40e-01  -9.0 1.83e-03  -4.5 1.00e+00 1.25e-01h  4 L
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  30  5.2234154e-02 2.91e-11 4.29e-08  -9.0 3.87e-03  -5.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1 LA
  31  5.2234151e-02 2.91e-11 2.17e-08  -9.0 5.87e-03  -5.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  32  5.2234138e-02 1.46e-11 2.18e-08  -9.0 1.77e-02  -5.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  33  5.2234099e-02 5.96e-08 2.18e-08  -9.0 5.29e-02  -6.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  34  5.2233984e-02 5.96e-08 2.16e-08  -9.0 1.57e-01  -6.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  35  5.2233647e-02 1.46e-11 2.11e-08  -9.0 4.61e-01  -7.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  36  5.2232686e-02 2.21e-11 1.96e-08  -9.0 1.29e+00  -7.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  37  5.2230211e-02 5.96e-08 1.60e-08  -9.0 3.16e+00  -8.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 LA
  38  5.2225108e-02 2.91e-11 9.58e-09  -9.0 5.66e+00  -8.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1 L
```

I already tried to change the Termination options, and I always get the same result. I can't understand why it run away from the starting point to a worse point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does not look like your starting point is optimal. We would expect `inf_du` to be very small immediately.

Comment: I'm new to optimization problems, and I don't understand the meaning of `inf_du`, what could cause it to be high? The objective value of the starting point is smaller then the final solution, and it is a feasible point. Isn't it enough to say it's a better point?

Comment: `inf_du` is dual infeasibility, a measure how close to optimality. Your initial point seems feasible as `inf_pr` is small at iteration 0..

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Seems like `inf_du` is always 1.00e+00 at iteration 0, no matter what is the starting point. I tried to use the IPOPT solution as the initial point, and this was the result:

`iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  5.2220306e-02 5.96e-08 1.00e+00  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0 
   1  5.2220306e-02 5.96e-08 1.30e+05  -1.0 3.50e+01    -  1.30e-02 1.68e-07f  6 
   2  5.2227778e-02 5.96e-08 9.73e+06  -1.0 2.08e+00    -  1.40e-02 1.00e+00f  1 Nhj`

Comment: IPOPT is not always very good in warm starts (due to the nature of interior point solvers). If you have good dual information available you can try to set the option `warm_start_init_point  yes `.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I tried it, and now `inf_du` starts in 4.55e-01 instead of 1.00e+00, but it didn't change the final answer. So, my main question keeps the same: if there's a feasible point with a better objective function value, why IPOPT converge to another solution?

Answer (score 1):

From: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.589.5002&rep=rep1&type=pdf at page 672.

As an interior point solver, it is difficult to warm start IPOPT. By default, only the level values of the variables are passed
as starting point to IPOPT. Setting the IPOPT option warm start init point to yes enables that also dual values for
variables and constraints are passed to IPOPT.
However, the expected behavior that IPOPT finishes within one iteration if optimal primal and dual values are passed is not
reached this way, yet. This is, because IPOPT by default moves any initial value that is close to a bound into the interior.

The amount on how much the initial point is moved can be controlled by various bound push and bound frac options. To
make IPOPT accept an optimal primal/dual solution within one iteration, it should be sufficient to set the following options:

```
warm_start_init_point yes
warm_start_bound_push 1e-9
warm_start_bound_frac 1e-9
warm_start_slack_bound_frac 1e-9
warm_start_slack_bound_push 1e-9
warm_start_mult_bound_push 1e-9
```